# How can I use a variable as regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I use `re` to find a word on a file and I stored it as `lattice_type` 
Now I want to use the word stored on `lattice_type` to make another regex

I tried using the name of the variable on this way

```
pnt_grp=re.match(r'+ lattice_type + (.*?) .*',line, re.M|re.I)
```

Here I look for the regex `lattice_type=` and store the `group(1)` in `lattice_type`

```
latt=open(cell_file,"r")
    for types in latt:
        line = types
        latt_type = re.match(r'lattice_type = (.*)', line, re.M|re.I)
        if latt_type:
            lattice_type=latt_type.group(1)
```

Here is where I want to use the variable containing the word to find it on another file, but I got problems

```
pg=open(parameters,"r")
    for lines in pg:
        line=lines
        pnt_grp=re.match(r'+ lattice_type + (.*?) .*',line, re.M|re.I)
        if pnt_grp:
            print(pnt_grp(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `r` prefix is only needed when defining a string with a lot of backslashes, because both regex and Python string syntax attach meaning to backslashes. `r'..'` is just an alternative syntax that makes it *easier* to work with regex patterns. You don't *have* to use `r'..'` raw string literals. See [*The backslash plague*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) in the Python regex howto for more information.

All that means that you certainly don't need to use the `r` prefix when already have a string value. A regex pattern is *just a string value*, and you can just use normal string formatting or concatenation techniques:

```
pnt_grp = re.match(lattice_type + '(.*?) .*', line, re.M|re.I)
```

I didn't use `r` in the string literal above, because there are no `\` backslashes in the expression there to cause issues.

You *may* need to use the [`re.escape()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) on your `lattice_type` value, if there is a possibility of that value containing regular expression meta-characters such as `.` or `?` or `[`, etc. `re.escape()` escapes such metacharacters so that only *literal text* is matched:

```
pnt_grp = re.match(re.escape(lattice_type) + '(.*?) .*', line, re.M|re.I)
```

Comment: I make the change but I obtain this:             at                                                                               '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not callable   because lattice_type is the match of tha later searching. How can I fix that?

Comment: @JorgeCastro: if `lattice_type` is a match object, then use a [match object method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) to get a string. Such as `lattice_type.group()`.